# How to write non-blocking, chunked RequestHandler in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, concurrent.futures

Here are two simple `RequestHandlers`:

```
class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        while True:
            future = Future()
            global_futures.add(future)
            s = yield future
            self.write(s)
            self.flush()


class AsyncHandler2(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        for f in global_futures:
            f.set_result(str(dt.now()))
        global_futures.clear()
        self.write("OK")
```

The first one "subscribes" to the stream, second one delivers message to all subscribers.

The problem is that I cannot have more than a bunch (in my case 5-6) subscribers. As soon as I subscribe more than allowed, the next request to the second method simply hangs.

I assume this is happening due to the first handler not being properly asynchronous. Is that because I am using global object to store list of subscribers?

How can I have more streaming requests open simultaneously, and what is a logical limit?

Comment: The problem was not related to the topic of the question, original issue is discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `global_futures` is being modified while you're iterating over it: when `AsyncHandler.get` wakes up, it runs from one `yield` to the next, meaning it creates its next Future and adds it to the set before control is returned to `AsyncHandler2`. This is undefined and the behavior depends on where the iterator is in the set: sometimes the new future is inserted "behind" the iterator and everything is fine, sometimes it's inserted "in front of" the iterator and the same consumer handler will be woken up a second time (and insert a third copy of itself which may be in front or behind...). When you only have a few consumers you'll hit the "behind" case often enough that things will work, but with too many it becomes extremely unlikely to ever finish.

The solution is to copy `global_futures` before iterating over it instead of clearing it at the end:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self);
    fs = list(global_futures)
    global_futures.clear()
    for f in fs:
        f.set_result(str(dt.now()))
    self.write("OK")
```

Note that I think this is only a problem in Tornado 4.x and older. In Tornado 5 things were changed so that `set_result` no longer calls into the waiting handler immediately, so there is no more concurrent modification.

Comment: Thank you, Ben, I appreciate your help. The issue turned out to be something completely unrelated to tornado, it is actually limit for concurrent connections per host in a browser - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser